# Equivalent optimization problem over simplex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have an linear program defined for variables over the non-negative orthant of the type:
\begin{align*}
    \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^K} &x^\top a
    \\ \text{subject to }& Ax = b
\end{align*}

Is there any way I can formulate this problem as an equivalent problem over the simplex $\Sigma = \{x\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^{K}: x^\top \mathbf{1} = 1\}$?

Comment: If $\bar x$ is the solution to your problem, you need $\bar x^\top\mathbf{1}>0$ in order  for it to be solvable over the simplex

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for way to reformulate (equivalently) the problem over the simplex let's say with variables $y\in\Sigma$, solve the equivalent problem and get the original problem solution $x = f(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original feasible region is bounded, you can enumerate the extreme points and express every feasible solution as a convex combination of the extreme points.  This idea is the basis for Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition.

Comment: can you elaborate more or refer to a source that explains the procedure? I have looked for Dantzig-wolfe decomposition but I don't see how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dantzig%E2%80%93Wolfe_decomposition.  The Chvatal reference there gives a good introduction.